# RDL or SSRS report only display values that aren't null or empty sets

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, rdl, iif

I have a report that has 3 fields in that I need to display but only want the fields to display if they have information in them not if they are null or empty sets.

Ex.  part number 1   -field 1 
                     -field 2
                     -field 3

```
 part number 2   -field 1

 part number 3   -field 2
                 -field 3

 part number 4   -field 1
                 -field 3
```

I've tried nested IIF statements, but I can't seem to get it without have a blank field appear.

Ex.  part number 4   -field 1
                     -blank
                     -field 3

Comment: Use a IIF(Isnothing(Field!DesiredField), True, False) in the visibility for the textbox.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't used the expressions that often. Do I need to define them as true and false or put values in those fields? For instance if true then field 1 + chr(13) + field 3?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It will help if you can edit your question to show the data you are trying to use in the form it comes from the dataset. Also show you report design layout. In most cases there is no need to manually hide nulls, with the correct design this will happen automatically.

Comment: @JordanPizarro Take a look at some of the expression examples.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @NewGuy they are are all in the same textbox for one expression is that matters.

Comment: =Trim(Fields!k3w_salesorderadditionaltext.Value)
 & IIF(Len(Trim(Replace(Fields!k3w_salesorderadditionaltext.Value, Chr(10), " "))) > 0 AndAlso Len(Trim(Fields!new_voltrngconfiguration.Value)) > 0, "", "")
 & Trim(Fields!new_voltrngconfiguration.Value)
 & IIF(Len(Trim(Replace(Fields!k3w_salesorderadditionaltext.Value, Chr(10), " "))) + IsNothing(Fields!new_voltrngconfiguration.Value) AndAlso Len(Trim(Fields!new_crmcomment.Value)) > 0, chr(10), "")
 & Trim(Fields!new_crmcomment.Value)

Comment: @NewGuy I've been looking at some of the expressions but the issue is displaying them. I need to have an IIF for field 1, field field and field 3 to display, one for field 2 and field 3 to display and one for field 1 and field 3 to display on sequential lines

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data and an image of your tablix?

Comment: How do you expect the report to display a value that is hull (meaning "no value there")?

Answer (score 0):

What you always can do in your tablix (I think its the easyiest way), go to **Tablix properties -> Filters**. Then add an filter. Like this for example:

```
'Expression
=Fields!YourFieldname.Value = Null orElse Fields!YourFieldname.Value = Nothing

'Data type
 Boolean

'Operator
 False
```

Now every value with **Null** or **Nothing** are filtered.